# SQL subquery multiple times error

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am making a subquery but I am getting a strange error

> The column 'RealEstateID' was specified multiple times for 'NotSold'.

here is my code

```
SELECT *
    FROM 
       (SELECT *
        FROM RealEstatesInfo AS REI
        LEFT JOIN Purchases AS P
        ON P.RealEstateID=REI.RealEstateID
        WHERE DateBought IS NULL) AS NotSold
INNER JOIN OwnerEstate AS OE
ON OE.RealEstateID=NotSold.RealEstateID
```

It's on SQL server by the way.

Comment: Replace the *'s with a list of the column names and you should see the issue.

Comment: Agree with @dfundako. You are returning 2 `RealEstateID` columns from your inner select. So these 2 columns `P.RealEstateID`,`REI.RealEstateID` will be aliased as `NotSold`. So your outer select is confused on what to Join to.

Comment: Oh i see now thanks

Answer (score 0):

That's because there will be 2 realestiteids in your subquery. You need to change it to explicitly list the columns from both table and only include 1 realestateid. It doesn't matter which as you use it for your join. 
If you're very Lazy you can select rei.* and only name the p cols apart from realestateid.

Btw select * is probably never a good idea in sub queries or derived tables or ctes.

Comment: yea i understood it, btw i am using the * since i am forming the query now and i will later change the * with the exact columns... idk if it's a good practice